# jQuery validation less than previous textbox value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am putting validation in a form for deal size and minimum investment. Here, minimum investment is must be < deal size. I have taken help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1261073/1578380), But it compares number of digits not arithmetic comparison and also it gives me an error message like:

> Please enter no more than 3 characters.

I want `"Enter minimum investment less than deal size."`

```
$('.deal-crud-validation').validate({
    rules: {
        digits: true,
        number: true,
        mininvestment: getRule()
    },
    message:{
        maxlength: "Enter minimum investment less than deal size"
    }      
});

$('.dealvalue').change(function () {
    $('.mininvestment').rules('remove', 'maxlength');
    $('.mininvestment').rules('add', getRule());
});
```

Comment: Show your `getRule()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken help from: [jquery validation for more than min value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349660/1578380)  get the solution

```
`$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan",
        function (value, element, param) {
            var $min = $(param);
            if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
                $min.off(".validate-greaterThan").on("blur.validate-greaterThan", function () {
                    $(element).valid();
                });
            }
            return parseInt(value) < parseInt($min.val());
        }, "Enter minimum investment less than deal size");

$('.deal-crud-validation').validate({
    rules: {
        mininvestment: {
            greaterThan: '.dealvalue'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or just a follow-up?  If this is not an answer to the question, then please use the "edit" link to update your OP.